# Change bound Id to separate model name

Tags: binding, model, knockout.js

So I have two separate models, one 'items' model, the second a 'sites'
model... I'm using KO to bind this data to two separate elements on
the DOM (and working as needed), but I've found a need to replace one
of my bound columns on one of my models, with data from the other.

On my 'items' model, I have a site ID column, that I'd love to swap
with the actual 'SiteName' property on that model (simple name, value-
pair - SiteName, SiteId)... Does any one know a way to do this within
KO?

I really want to keep the model data itself in tact on the server side,
verses just creating a custom model on the server side that does it for me.

I'm sure I could give those elements a special class, and loop
through them and replace them manually with jQuery, but I thought that
KO might have an easier way of doing this.

Thanks!

I have tried something like this, but it doesn't seem to work (yes, I know div tags within a table element are not standards based, I just wanted to see if it would work, and if it did, I'd transition from the table to another formatting option)

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
        <tr data-bind="click: updateItem">
            <td data-bind="text: ItemName"></td>
            <div data-bind="foreach: sites">
                <div data-bind="if: items.SiteId = sites.SiteId">
                    <td data-bind="text: sites.SiteName"></td>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery to do this using my returned model is:

```
$(function () {
            $('#allItems tr .siteIdCell').each(function () {
                for (i in allSites) {
                    if (allSites[i].SiteId == $(this).html()) {
                        $(this).html(allSites[i].SiteName);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Where .siteIdCell is the class I applied to the columns using this value, and allSites is the object array I'm receiving via JSON.

Not sure if I'll get many responses, but I just figured I'd update this if anyone else has the same issue, and there's no ability to do this in KO.